# Microsoft sync framework Authentication

Tags: web-services, authentication, asp-classic, synchronization

I'm very novice when it comes to web applications and ASP.

Recently, I've been experimenting with the Microsoft Sync Toolkit to synchronize databases over a OData web service.

The obvious question here is: Once the service is set up and published - so it is open for anyone knowing the URL - how to prevent unauthorized users from accessing this service.

Please note: Basic authentication of forms authentication - as far my little web development knowledge reaches - doesn't seem to be appropriate for this task, as it's not a web page that the client is trying to reach - where the page can display / or re-direct a logon request - it's a service that we are accessing here.

To make things more difficult, for the client-side syncing I'm using a 3rd party library/sync-provider that only accepts a URL for the service. So, there's no way (I think) I can experiment with incorporating login credentials inside a request header etc.

I assume the best bet would be embedding the login credentials inside the URL and use that for the 3rd party library.

Can somebody please direct me how to to set up such thing on the server? I would prefer to have somehow somewhere in the server-side code a place where I can check for the credentials and based upon it to proceed or abort (return 401) the service request.

I could not find any place where to hook such code into the sync service. Although somebody in MSDN suggested to handle the _OnBeginSyncRequest event, there is no way to access the web-request header from within that method.

Is there by-any-chance a global object accessible from everywhere from which I can access the request header? Could anyone please help with this?

And last, I would prefer a plain User / Password string pair. It should not necessarily (or rather not) have anything to do with windows or directory accounts. I would prefer in my code to simple check against plain strings, such if(userStr == "Authenticated user" && passwordStr == "Correct Password").

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SOAP web service, you can use WS-Security usernametoken which adds your user name and password to the request header, otherwise you can add username and password as parameters in your webservice and then simply validate it on the server side.  i.e.

instead of

```
bool SyncData(datatable)
```

it becomes

```
bool SyncData(datatable, username, password)
```

note for web service you will authenticate per call, if you want to do it per session, you need first login with username password, retrieves a token than on each subsequent call your service with the token.

You would also use SSL to secure the channel so username and password aren't transmitted as plain text.